# Getting AutoLayout error while Parsing a JSON in Swift 2

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, autolayout

so here's the problem: I need to populate a basic `UITableView` using the data contained inside a **JSON** document. To parse it, I used the code below (works like a charm):

```
let urlPath = "http://mywebsite.com/jsonDocument"
        let endpoint = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:endpoint!)

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            self.data_string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("JSON Downloaded")

            self.UpdateTV()
        }.resume()
```

`UpdateTV` is basically a function that sorts the obtained data and streams it to the table view, calling a `reloadData` at the end of the process.

At this point not only everything becomes **incredibly slow**... but **XCode** also gets messy with this error (multiplied for each `UITableViewCell`)

```
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
 Stack:(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a5bef45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c7bedeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a5bee7d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010ad58289 _AssertAutolayoutOnMainThreadOnly + 79
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010abb84e2 -[NSISEngine optimize] + 49
    5   Foundation                          0x000000010abb8da4 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 245
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010bb79a4b -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 58
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010bb7a3cd -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 154
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010bb7a03d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 309
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010bb7a3f9 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 198
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010bb79a54 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 67
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010bb7a7dc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 844
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010bb7b2a3 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 272
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010b35c332 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 159
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010b36be67 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 749
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110ea859a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110e9ce70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010b35baa1 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1083
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010b624f63 -[UITableViewCell _setFrame:skipLayout:] + 373
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010b624de8 -[UITableViewCell setFrame:] + 58
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010b40270f __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 3228
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010b360c10 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010b401a5a -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 475
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010b40ce58 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 828
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010b40cf3f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010b3e2307 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3187
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010b3e2d57 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 5827
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010b3e2d57 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 5827
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010b3e2d57 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 5827
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010b3e2d57 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 5827
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010b3e2d57 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 5827
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010b3e2d57 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 5827
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010b3e2d57 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 5827
    33  UIKit                               0x000000010b415d1c -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
    34  UIKit                               0x000000010b3fd884 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 223
    35  UIKit                               0x000000010b36be40 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
    36  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110ea859a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    37  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110e9ce70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    38  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110e9ccee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    39  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110e91475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    40  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110ebec0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    41  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110ebeefc _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 224
    42  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d5d839c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 470
    43  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d5d7f78 _pthread_exit + 117
    44  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d5d6596 pthread_attr_getschedpolicy + 0
    45  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d5d4375 start_wqthread + 13
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON parsing has nothing to do with Autolayout. Your problem is that you update UI in background thread. Every job with UI must be done in main thread, so you can change your code like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    // update UI here
    self.updateViews()
})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your stacktrace. You are updating the tableView in a background thread. You should instead do this where you call reloadData.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```